# "An unknown server-side error" when tried to launch android app of real android phone

Tags: java, android, appium

Below is the code I am using, I have double checked the package name and activity name using apk info app and they are correct. I have been stuck with this from couple of hours, someone please help me.

I am running the app on the real android phone.

public class FirstMobileAutoTest 
{

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Arjun");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "3401673bb40b368d"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.socialnmobile.colornote.activity.Search");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
```

//          caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

```
        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
                AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

Below are the adb logs.

```
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:appActivity": "io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos"
,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:appPackage": "com.google.android.packageinstall
er",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Arjun",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "10.0",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "3401673bb40b368d"
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: cef5707c-3c43-43b2-b0f7-05860dee9d
81
[UiAutomator2] Starting 'com.google.android.packageinstaller' directly on the de
vice
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-t
ools\adb.exe'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"3401673bb40b368d","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: 3401673bb40b368d
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-t
ools\adb.exe'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to 3401673bb40b368d
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 29
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 29
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_
pre_p_apps 1'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_
p_apps 1'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings put global hidden_api_policy
1'
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d wait-for-device'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell echo ping'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater
or equal to the application version name ('3.1.0' >= '3.1.0')
[debug] [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roami
ng\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-deb
ug.apk'
[debug] [ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need
to reset its permissions.
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell appops set io.appium.settings android\
:mock_location allow'
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8200
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790'
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2
.server'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2
.server'
[debug] [ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.5.5' >= '4.5.5')
[debug] [UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: sameVer
sionInstalled
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-ser
ver-v4.5.5.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner.jar' from 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\buil
d-tools\29.0.3\lib\apksigner.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241\\bin\\j
ava.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar C:\\Users\\Rohini\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\
build-tools\\29.0.3\\lib\\apksigner.jar verify --print-certs C:\\Users\\Rohini\\
AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-s
erver\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk
[debug] [ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@a
ndroid.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C
=US
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c
454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b
0bfaa5af81
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87

[debug] [ADB]
[debug] [ADB] 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modu
les\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' is si
gned with the default certificate
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2
.server.test'
[debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-ser
ver-debug-androidTest.apk
[debug] [ADB] Starting apksigner: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241\\bin\\j
ava.exe' -Xmx1024M -Xss1m -jar C:\\Users\\Rohini\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\
build-tools\\29.0.3\\lib\\apksigner.jar verify --print-certs C:\\Users\\Rohini\\
AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-s
erver\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
[debug] [ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@a
ndroid.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C
=US
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c
454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b
0bfaa5af81
[debug] [ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87

[debug] [ADB]
[debug] [ADB] 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modu
les\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest
.apk' is signed with the default certificate
[UiAutomator2] Server packages are not going to be (re)installed
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for services to be available
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell pm list instrumentation'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Instrumentation target 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.tes
t/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' is available
[debug] [UiAutomator2] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for com.google.android.packageinstaller
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys package com.google.android.pac
kageinstaller'
[debug] [ADB] 'com.google.android.packageinstaller' is installed
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell am force-stop com.google.android.packa
geinstaller'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell pm clear com.google.android.packageins
taller'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'com.google.androi
d.packageinstaller' application (stop and clear)
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[debug] [UiAutomator2] No obsolete sessions have been detected (Error: socket ha
ng up)
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.s
erver.test'
[UiAutomator2] Starting UIAutomator2 server 4.5.5
[UiAutomator2] Using UIAutomator2 server from 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiaut
omator2-server-v4.5.5.apk' and test from 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomato
r2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","3401673bb40b36
8d","shell","am","instrument","-w","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.
test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/s
tatus] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with unknown status: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/s
tatus] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with unknown status: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[debug] [Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2S
erver:
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/s
tatus] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with unknown status: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/s
tatus] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"None","value":{"r
eady":true,"message":"UiAutomator2 Server is ready to accept commands"}}
[debug] [UiAutomator2] The initialization of the instrumentation process took 42
25ms
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hu
b/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webSto
rageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnab
led":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warni
ngs":{},"desired":{"platformName":"android","appActivity":"io.appium.android.api
s.ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.google.android.packageinstaller","deviceName":"Arj
un","platformVersion":"10.0","udid":"3401673bb40b368d"},"platformName":"android"
,"appActivity":"io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.google.androi
d.packageinstaller","deviceName":"3401673bb40b368d","platformVersion":"10.0","ud
id":"3401673bb40b368d","deviceUDID":"3401673bb40b368d"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"4920b02f-d13c-481
d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3","value":{"sessionId":"4920b02f-d13c-481d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3"
,"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"ta
kesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkCon
nectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"pl
atformName":"android","appActivity":"io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos","appPackag
e":"com.google.android.packageinstaller","deviceName":"Arjun","platformVersion":
"10.0","udid":"3401673bb40b368d"},"platformName":"android","appActivity":"io.app
ium.android.apis.ApiDemos","appPackage":"com.google.android.packageinstaller","d
eviceName":"3401673bb40b368d","platformVersion":"10.0","udid":"3401673bb40b368d"
,"deviceUDID":"3401673bb40b368d"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}}
[WD Proxy] Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/info] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8
200/wd/hub/session/4920b02f-d13c-481d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3/appium/device/info] with
 no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"4920b02f-d13c-481
d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3","value":{"androidId":"98793d3af233dac2","manufacturer":"sam
sung","model":"SM-M205F","brand":"samsung","apiVersion":"29","platformVersion":"
10","carrierName":"Jio 4G","realDisplaySize":"1080x2340","displayDensity":420,"n
etworks":[{"type":0,"typeName":"MOBILE","subtype":13,"subtypeName":"LTE","isConn
ected":true,"detailedState":"CONNECTED","state":"CONNECTED","extraInfo":"IMS","i
sAvailable":true,"isFailover":false,"isRoaming":false,"capabilities":{"transport
Types":"TRANSPORT_CELLULAR","networkCapabilities":"NET_CAPABILITY_IMS,NET_CAPABI
LITY_NOT_METERED,NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN,NET_CAPABILITY_VA
LIDATED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING,NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_
CONGESTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED","linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":51200,"linkD
ownBandwidthKbps":102400,"signalStrength":-2147483648,"networkSpecifier":"1","SS
ID":null}},{"type":1,"typeName":"WIFI","subtype":0,"subtypeName":"","isConnected
":true,"detailedState":"CONNEC...
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell dumpsys window'
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[UiAutomator2] Starting 'com.google.android.packageinstaller/io.appium.android.a
pis.ApiDemos and waiting for 'com.google.android.packageinstaller/io.appium.andr
oid.apis.ApiDemos'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell am start -W -n com.google.android.pack
ageinstaller/io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c
 android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[debug] [ADB] We tried to start an activity that doesn't exist, retrying with '.
io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos' activity name
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell am start -W -n com.google.android.pack
ageinstaller/.io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -
c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/s
ession/4920b02f-d13c-481d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"4920b02f-d13c-481
d-9678-3360c1c0c2c3","value":null}
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell am force-stop com.google.android.packa
geinstaller'
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings delete global hidden_api_poli
cy_pre_p_apps'
[debug] [Instrumentation] .
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings delete global hidden_api_poli
cy_p_apps'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3401673bb40b368d shell settings delete global hidden_api_poli
cy'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1585053387258 (18:06:27
 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start th
e 'com.google.android.packageinstaller' application. Visit https://github.com/ap
pium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.
md for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.google.android.pac
kageinstaller' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/d
ocs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. O
riginal error: Activity name '.io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos' used to start th
e app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchab
le activity
[debug] [W3C]     at ADB.startApp (C:\Users\Rohini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:165:11)
[debug] [W3C] Destroying socket connection
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 13158 ms - 1735
[HTTP]
[debug] [Instrumentation] Time: 3.041
[debug] [Instrumentation]
[debug] [Instrumentation] OK (1 test)
[debug] [Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is very clear: **Activity name '.io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos' used to start th
e app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchab
le activity**

you just need to put correct activity name in `appActivity` capability